# 0V with Electronic Load and CC Buck

Tags: buck, constant-current, electronic-load

Why would an electronic load show 0 V and a big current when connected to a constant current source?

The load is in constant current mode. Is that the culprit? Probably a constant impedance would be better?

Answer (score 2):

If you test a buck constant current source using a load set to constant current, both will try to set the current and fight each other.

Suppose the buck wants 1A but the load wants 0.99A. The buck will crank output voltage to maximum in an attempt to increase current, but the load will still draw 0.99A.

Suppose the buck wants 1A but the load wants 1.01A. The load tries to draw more current than the source can provide, so voltage will drop as much as it can, to zero (or near zero).

Some buck chips have restrictions on maximum and minimum output voltage. The first case might trigger overvoltage protection, the second might trigger a short circuit protection or foldback. If that happens, you're not necessarily trimming the real output current.

You should set the electronic load to a mode that mimics your real load. For example if your load is a LED, use constant voltage drop (an ammeter in series with the intended LED would work just as well as a bench electronic load). If the load is a resistor... then set it to resistor mode.

It will be much easier to adjust the buck current too, because it will stop jumping all over the place when trimming.

An electronic load has a feedback loop. Your buck current source also has a feedback loop. Both may interact in sometimes unpredictable manner, depending how they're built. For example, if the load really is a current sink which is controlled by a feedback loop which makes it emulate a resistor (or a LED) then... outside of the bandwidth of the feedback loop... it's a current sink. So its frequency-dependent impedance can look a bit weird.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes total sense. I was under the impression when I set the electronic load to considerably higher CC current than the CC threshold at the buck that the buck would "act first", not considering how CC actually regulates both ends. I'll try the other modes.